# Serverless Framework does not create SQS queue before Lambda with queue trigger

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, serverless-framework

Using Serverless Framework, how can I make my Lambda function depend on an SQS queue from the `resources` section as it is the trigger for the function itself?

In my `serverless.yaml`, I am defining a new queue and Lambda function.

Then, I want to use the queue as an event source (trigger) for my Lambda function.

I do that by creating the queue ARN manually:

```yaml
functions:
  consumer:
    handler: App\Service\Consumer
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn:
            Fn::Join:
              - ':'
              - arn:aws:sqs
              - Ref: AWS::Region
              - Ref: AWS::AccountId
              - ${opt:stage}-skill-assigner
```

And creating the queue in resources:

```yaml
resources:
  Resources:
    SkillAssignerQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: ${opt:stage}-skill-assigner
```

This works fine if I create the queue in a deployment prior to using it as a function trigger.

But if I try to deploy both of them, it fails with this error when it tries to create the event source mapping:

> Invalid request provided: Error occurred while ReceiveMessage. SQS Error Code: AWS.SimpleQueueService.NonExistentQueue. SQS Error Message: The specified queue does not exist for this wsdl version.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Fn::Join` enables string concatenation which doesn't inform the Serverless Framework (SF) about the dependency of the function on the queue.

We *visually* can see that but it needs to be done *declaratively*.

**To make this link obvious to SF, use `Fn::GetAtt:` instead.**

It will inform Serverless Framework about the dependency of the Lambda function on the SQS queue.

This should work:

```yaml
functions:
  consumer:
    handler: App\Service\Consumer
    events:
      - sqs:
          arn:
            Fn::GetAtt:
              - SkillAssignerQueue
              - Arn
resources:
  Resources:
    SkillAssignerQueue:
      Type: AWS::SQS::Queue
      Properties:
        QueueName: ${opt:stage}-skill-assigner
```

Answer (score -1):

The Serveless Framework can automatically create the queue for you. No need to define it in resources

Comment: [SF docs](https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/sqs), in bold: `Note: The sqs event will hook up your existing SQS Queue to a Lambda function. Serverless won't create a new queue for you.`